# How do I display random images to a table

Tags: javascript, html, image, html-table

I have a table and a folder of images. I want to randomly insert an image into each cell of the table when the page loads, using html and javascript. I also want the order of the images to be different on every refresh and not have any of them repeat. So far my html looks something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src"" id="00></td>
        <td><img src"" id="01></td>
        <td><img src"" id="02></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src"" id="10></td>
        <td><img src"" id="11></td>
        <td><img src"" id="12></td>
    </tr>...
</table>
```

And my js looks something like this:

```
window.onload = showPics;
let myPics = new Array('images/butterfly.jpg', 'images/cat.jpg', 'images/dinosaur.jpg',
                       'images/dog.jpg', 'images/duck.jpg', 'images/elephant.jpg');

function showPics() {
    let randomPic = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPics.length);
    document.querySelectorAll('#00, #01, #02, #10, #11, #12').src = myPics[randomPic];
```

However the images are not being displayed. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.querySelectorAll()` returns array, so you need to loop it. Also you should call `new random` for each element, not once, otherwise it will contain same image

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let myPics = ['https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=1', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=2', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=3',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=4', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=5', 'https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=6'
  ];

  function showPics() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.img').forEach(function(tag) {
      let index = getRandomIndex();
      tag.src = myPics[index];
      tag.addEventListener('click', getImageName);
      tag.dataset.index = index;
    })
  }

  function getRandomIndex() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * myPics.length);
  }

  function getImageName() {
     alert(myPics[this.dataset.index])
  }

  showPics();
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src "" class="img"></td>
    <td><img src "" class="img"></td>
    <td><img src "" class="img"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src "" class="img"></td>
    <td><img src "" class="img"></td>
    <td><img src "" class="img"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

In order to have non-repeating images, keep track of indexes, that you already used (make sure you have more or same amount of images then the placeholders).

```
let usedImages = {};

function getRandomPic {
    let randomPic;

    do {
        randomPic = Math.floor(Math.random() * myPics.length);
    } while (usedImages[randomPic] === true);

    usedImages[randomPic] = true;

    return myPics[randomPic];
}
```

Comment: Now that my images are arranged randomly in the table, I am wondering if it is possible to click on one of them and obtain its array index? Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Put it to `data-index` attribute with `dataset.index`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Thanks again Justinas, however I think my comment was unclear. I want to be able to click on an image in the table and return its array index as a string. For example, click on the butterfly and get 'images/butterfly.jpg'. Is this possible? I have tried the indexOf method but I always receive -1

Comment: @sgt_pepper85 I understood your question, but you misunderstood my answer. Check updated answer.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you again

Comment: Sorry, just one more problem, with the amended code some of the images are repeating again. I can't work out how to fix this...

Comment: re-run random calculation until you reach still not used image - check my last paragraph in answer

Comment: I was also able to get the source of the image using this: 
    $('.img').click(function() {
        var path = $(this).attr('src');    
    });

Answer (score 1):

add a class like `changing` Images in the all images that you wanna change and change `showPics`like this, and you dont neet to put `new` keyword for creating of a array `[]` will work fine, and dont store the random image in a variable that will always give you same image.

```js
function showPics() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.changeImages').forEach(val => {
      val.src = myPics[Number(Math.floor(Math.random() * myPics.length))];
    })   
}
```